# How typescript can change the content(On off switch) in scss file

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sass

I have an on-off switch like this.
[image]

[image]

Now I want to change the word (On) inside the switch to another word (e.g: cc, cv ) that will be based on a boolean. For example, If the variable1 is True then display 'cc' in the switch. if the variable2 is True then display 'cv' in the switch. Both varaible1 and variable2 cannot be True at the same time, so don't worry.

Here is my code in HTML file and scss file

HTML:

```
      <div> 
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" [ionSetting]="outputEnabled" style="display: none;">
          <span class="slider"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
```

SCSS file:

```
//Start: On/Off switch-->
.switch {
  top: 12.5%;
  right: 1%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 22px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.3vw;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

//Hide the Checkbox behide the switch
.switch input {
  display: none;
}

//Sheild border and radius
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: solid 1px rgb(184, 186, 191);
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.slider:hover {
  border: solid 1px rgb(224, 226, 231);
}
//Button inside the switch
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(184, 186, 191);
  height: 16px;
  width: 27px;
  content: "";
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s; //ease-in-out
}

.slider:hover:before {
  background-color: rgb(224, 226, 231);
}
.slider:hover:after {
  color: rgb(224, 226, 231);
}

.slider:after {
  content: "Off";
  color: rgb(184, 186, 191);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 75%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

//checked condition
input:checked + .slider:after {
  transition: 0.5s;
  left: 25%;
  content: "On";
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: rgb(76, 142, 255);
  border: solid 2px rgb(76, 142, 255);
}

input:checked + .slider:hover {
  background-color: rgb(111, 179, 255);
  border: solid 2px rgb(111, 179, 255);
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translate(26px, -1px);
  background-color: white;
}
//End: On/Off switch <--
```

Since SCSS file cannot access the variable in typescript, then the only way is from typescript to change the content in SCSS file, right? OR have any better suggestions?

Comment: You will have to use two preexisting classes which you`re going to activate with the ngClass directive.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to add two classes for input:checked + .slider:after  and change the content?